# I need vertical and horizontal text to merge using CSS, like the image attached

Tags: html, css

[image]

I tried using CSS but didn't get exact output I wanted

**CSS I used**:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif JP', serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
date {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif JP', serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

span {
  -webkit-text-combine: horizontal; /* Safari */
  text-combine-upright: digits 2;
}
```

**HTML Code I used**:

```html
<div>
  <p>NITIN</p>
  <date
    ><span>N</span><span>I</span><span>T</span><span>I</span
    ><span>N</span></date
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

**Codepen Example:** https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/YzGxVoZ

```css
body {
  font-family: "Noto Serif JP", serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
div {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
.notThis {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span class="notThis">NITIN</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>N</span>
</div>
```